# Gradient steepest ascent interpretation breakdown

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

We tend to be taught to interpret the gradient to be the direction of steepest ascent of a vector valued function.

However, I'm confused as to why when we reach the minimum of a function, say f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2, we no longer expect the gradient to tell us how to increase. We're at a minimum,so certainly this instrument that tells us how which direction we should move in so that we increase the value of the function should be useful, no? Instead it fails to tell us where to go to increase and just yields a zero vector.

Should I interpret this as meaning that the interpretation of the gradient as telling us the direction of steepest ascent breaks down at the minimum/maximum? That this is simply not always true and that its truest definition is that it represents rates of change? Does this have a deeper mathematical meaning?

Comment: At a minimum, the gradient has to be $0$, otherwise you could move a little but in the direction opposite to the gradient and the function value would decrease. When the gradient is $0$ at a point $x$, it tells us that $f(x + h) = o(h)$ and that we need to look at 2nd derivatives or higher to understand how it changes when $h$ is small.

Comment: Forgetting the complications of multivariable calculus we see that the minimum and maximum of a smooth real function occur when the slope is $0$. However for a function like $f(x)=x^3$ we can get slope $0$ without extrema and it gives us no information about which way the function increases or decreases. The gradient is no different.